# Java Ice and IOException

Tags: java, interface, ioexception, ice

I'm trying to make an Java Ice code and i have some issues with exceptions in interfaces (with IOException). I write in the slice ".ice"

```
module Demo {
    
    
    
        struct Pedido{
        string nombre;
        string comanda;
        string direccion;
        string tarjeta;
    };
    
    interface Fichero {
        string getNombre(Pedido p);
        string getComanda(Pedido p);
        string getDireccion(Pedido p);
        string getTarjeta (Pedido p);
        string descifrado(string tarjeta);
        void escribirFichero(Pedido p) ;
        
    };
    
    

    interface Pedidos {
        float getPrecioTotal(Pedido p);
        float getPrecio(string item);
        void devolverPrecio(Pedido p, out float res);
    };
};
```

In the interface fichero, I have problems of exceptions IOException.

What can i do?

Comment: "some issues with exceptions in interfaces" is incredibly vague. Can you be more specific? What **exact** error messages do you get ([edit] your question to include them).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.